# NextJS not updating data from getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, next.js

I have a NextJS web app and NestJS backend. Locally with `npm run dev` or `npm run build && npm start` all works fine.

But deployed app (front and back in docker on different servers) not updating data on `groups` page.

When I build my app it generates a page with data from backend. Then I can add a new `group` (just new data), return to the group's page and can not see my mewGroup in the list.

My `getStaticProps` (not working):

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<GroupProps> = async () => {
  const { getGroups, getUsers, getModules } = useHttp();
  const { data: groups } = await getGroups();

  const { data: users } = await getUsers();

  const { data: modules } = await getModules();

  return {
    props: { groups, users, modules },
    revalidate: 5
  };
};
```

My post request (working):

```js
createGroup(body)
      .then(() => {
        push(routes.groups);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throwError && throwError(error);
      });
```

Again, it works fine locally even with the production backend.
But production web does not update any info, just can push some.

It's my first NextJS app, but I worked with react.

In my production logs I see the error, but have no idea how to handle it:

```js
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN {{MY_BACK_SERVER}}
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:71:26) {
  errno: -3001,
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '{{MY_BACK_SERVER}}',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.24.0'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://{{MY_BACK_SERVER}}:5000/groups',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/groups',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: '{{MY_BACK_SERVER}}',
      port: '5000',
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/groups'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /groups HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.24.0\r\n' +
        'Host: {{MY_BACK_SERVER}}:5000\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/groups',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: '{{MY_BACK_SERVER}}',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://{{MY_BACK_SERVER}}:5000/groups',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so when you first open the group page it showed you the information from the static file,

there are two cases -

> 1. now if there is a modification in the data (ie befor opening the group page for the first time) it will show you the old data (as it works with stale
>    while revalidate cache) and update the data (in background) for group page
>    (getStaticProps ). so when you again visit the group page again it
>    will show you the updated data.
> 2. Now the second case is (the one related to you) you opened the group page it checks there is no need to update the page in the
>    background as there is no new data in the server, it shows you the
>    data and then you in the same session updated the group info (added a
>    new data), next js will not show those newly created data because from
>    here it is serving you pages from the local cache. just because it
>    doesn't see any update of data in the first render.

You will have to do a full refresh to see the newly created data.

recommendation - use full page refresh occasionally (programmatically) when you think there may be a new data created or user server side rendering.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I still do not understand, I use `revalidate: 5` - why is it not enough to update data (and why is it enough locally?)? And I see the error (last code-block in my question) when next trying to send GET request to groups API route. Error while next trying to update data.

Comment: You will have to learn about cache control headers and how it works. Revalidate won't work on 2nd case because the page is not coming from server, it is there in you browser,(you opened the same page previously and now it is in browser memory).  If the page is fetched by server, Revalidate will work.

Comment: If you are seeing result during development this is because every page whether using getstaicprops or getserversideprops are generated dynamically. Caching is off and in production there is caching.

Comment: refreshInterval: 1000, revalidateOnMount: true

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve the problem. My container has no internet connection, SSR just can't ping the backend. POST request works well because it client-side request.